# Why does "opacity:0" become interpreted as "display: none!important"?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to be able to click on an element with class `.cancel` and transition to hiding my modal. However, the transition isn't happening because when I inspect the page using my Chrome browser, the `opacity` property isn't showing up, but rather `display: none !important` shows up instead. If I adjust the CSS in the inspector to `opacity: 0` (like I wanted), then the transition works just fine.

I'd love to know why the `opacity` is being replaced by `display: none !important`. A snippet of the relevant code is as follows:

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal-edit {
    position: fixed;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 340px;
    background: white;
    border: solid 2px gray;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /*-webkit-transition: opacity 2s;*/
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

I also included Bootstrap in my project, in case that matters:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Remember that hiding an element with `opacity` will not remove it from the document. i.e. You will not be able to select text / click links underneath the transparent element. You will need to move the modal in some way, use `display: none` once the transition has taken place, or [use `pointer-events: none`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) on the modal when hidden.

Comment: How would you go about adding `display: none` once the transition's taken place? Would this be something that jQuery takes care of, or can you do it in the CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap css adds some [styling](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-show-hide) when you add a class of `.hidden`:

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

So this would seem unrelated to your opacity specification. Try using a different class selector for the opacity

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue!